# Apache / Glassfish integration

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-proxy, glassfish

So I currently have a glassfish 3.1 server and an apache 2.2 server running on a single box. However I am trying to figure out to route some traffic through the apache server to the glassfish server in order to hide the non-standard ports 8080,8181. I also have static content being served up on the apache server. I have done some searching and have read several examples that talk about doing this, however I am really new to apache and I am not understanding the virtualhost and mod_proxy stuff. Any help understanding these, and how to accomplish what I am trying to do would be great.

**EDIT**

Per Shane example I tried the following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forum.mydomain.com
    # any logging config, etc, that you need
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/
</VirtualHost>
```

But now all my traffic is going to http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/ and for some reason all the images are missing. So let me better explain my scenario. I have an apache server that serves up static pages, those pages are access from mydomain.com. Than I have a forum which runs as a web app on my glassfish server and they are served on mydomain.com:8080/forum/ what I would like to do is have forum.mydomain.com go to the mydomain.com:8080/forum/ but hide the port 8080 from the user. Let me know what you think.

**EDIT PART 2**

So since my last attempt did not work I decided to try another deviation of Shane's examples so I tried the following.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"

    <Location /forum>
       ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/
       ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But this did not work either, now if I hit mydomain.com it takes me to mydomain.com//forums/list.page but it is a 404 Error (I think this is strange because it obviously got to the glassfish server because it re-routed to the list.page). However if I go to subdomain.mydomain.com it takes me to my normal static web pages. I feel like I have to be close but I am just not sure what is wrong. In this example I was hoping that mydomain.com and subdomain.mydomain.com would take me to my static pages, and mydomain.com/forum/ would take me to my forum app on glassfish.

**EDIT Part 3 Final?**

So I finally got the routing how I wanted it BUT for some reason the forum is missing all of its images. I ended up doing it with the following.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.mydomain.com mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forum.mydomain.com
    # any logging config, etc, that you need
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I just need to figure out the image problem . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the `ProxyPass` directives can serve requests to a location with content from a different HTTP (or AJP) server.

Here's an example config with comments that might help clarify:

```
# We'll call this your existing vhost:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/www/
    # other existing config
    # Let's say you want to serve http://example.com/glassfishapp from the 8080 listener:
    <Location /glassfishapp>
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# Now, let's say there's a whole domain you want to serve from the 8181 listener:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName glass.example.com
    # any logging config, etc, that you need
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8181/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8181/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hello, so I tried this but it didn't work. <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forum.mydomain.com
    # any logging config, etc, that you need
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/forum/
</VirtualHost>
Where /forum/ is a webapp running on my glassfish instance on port 8080

Comment: Please edit your question with this new info, since it can be formatted correctly.  And please clarify "didn't work" - what happens instead?  Your `<VirtualHost>` definition will need to match with a `NameVirtualHost` and your existing `<VirtualHost>`, as well..

Comment: Okay I modified my question for you, thanks for your help.

Comment: (re: forum image problem) Your proxy configuration is removing `/forum` from the path - check the HTML source in your browser, it's likely that it has the `/forum` path hardcoded.